# How to diagnose a "resource is not available" error Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to set up a servlet that shows a simple HTML page but when I run the apache server I get the below error although the file is located in the project.

Does anyone know how I can diagnose the problem? I don't see any stack trace or error list as usual with a java application

The web.xnl file declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is the example I'm following:

http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx

[image: resource not found]

[image]

Comment: Double check how you've registered your Servlet.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you explain how to register the servlet? not too familiar with this process.

Comment: That's kind of broad topic (so is debugging a 404). Does your app have a `web.xml` or have you use `@WebServlet` or directly through the `ServletContext`?

Comment: I'm using a web.xml file, I'll post it above.

Comment: Notice your `url-pattern`. Then look at the URL of your request.

Comment: yes I can see that the `url-pattern` is different from the servlet class name. Does this mean the patttern should be changed to `HelloWorld`

Comment: [Here are the rules for `url-pattern` matching.](http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/) You sent a request to `/FibonacciServlet/servlet/HelloWorld`. Assuming `/FibonacciServlet` is your web application context path, the target path is `/servlet/HelloWorld/`. But your servlet is mapped to `/HelloServlet`. Obviously those don't match, so your servlet won't handle that request.

Comment: Okay so I must change the url pattern to the same name as my servlet class? Then it would be `<url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>`.

Comment: I changed the url pattern to HelloWorld but I'm still getting the same `resource not found` error.

Comment: Check that your webapp is deployed correctly with your servlet container.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check this, how would I go about checking this?

Comment: The tutorial you are following shows how to add projects to embedded tomcat server instances. Have you done this?

Comment: yes, I added the project "FibonacciServlet" by right clicking on the server instance and adding the project but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give correct URL as mentioned by gurav.
 
If u want the same URL change **HelloServlet** to **/servlet/HelloWorld** in web-inf s url- pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL :

```
http://localhost:8080/FibonacciServlet/HelloServlet
```

I am assuming that the name is webapplication deployed is FibonacciServlet

Comment: I tried that url after restarting the server but get the same error:  `HTTP Status 404 - /FibonacciServlet/HelloServlet

type Status report

message /FibonacciServlet/HelloServlet

description The requested resource is not available.`